# Proper loss function for sequence prediction model with multi-step output

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, rnn, sequence

Consider a typical time series (sequence) prediction problem that use previous $k$ step historical features to predict the next step target. We use `RNN` model as an example.

[image]

As shown in the picture, {$x_0$,...,$x_k$} is the sequence of historical features used to predict the target $y_{k+1}$ at step $k+1$. Typical method uses only the final output $\hat{y}_{k+1}$ for training and the corresponding loss will be, for example, `mse` as $||y_{k+1}-\hat{y}_{k+1}||_2$. Thus, I have following few questions.

Q1: Though {$y_1,...,y_k$} is known at time step $k$, will it be better to use last multiple (even all) steps of outputs for prediction than using only the last one $\hat{y}_k$ ? For example, using `mse` for multiple steps outputs as

$$loss=\frac{1}{N+1}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{N} ||\hat{y}_{k+1-n}-y_{k+1-n}||_2 $$

Q2: How to choose a proper loss function for multiple outputs ? It seems the multi-step `mse` is not a good choice when the rank between $y$ and $\hat{y}$ is  prefered than absolute deviation.